# GregorianCalendar last year day of the week

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel

I have an excel sheet with a column date from 2003 (format : 2015/02/10) and column sales. I want to extract( last year,current week, today's day name )sales numbers.  like today is Thursday, Feb 12, Well the equivalent "Thursday" from last year was on Feb 13.
  I have tried my code below but I'm getting error "cannot convert string "Thursday" to double" any idea how to ? thank you

```
 Dim MyCalendar As Calendar = New GregorianCalendar
    Dim culture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("EN-US")
    dim eventcal as new datatable
    Dim dayname As String = culture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(Now.DayOfWeek)

    Dim lastCurrentweek = MyCalendar.GetWeekOfYear(
      Now,
      CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek,
      DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    Dim lastCurrentyear = MyCalendar.GetYear(Now) - 1
        dim dayrecord = (From Row In eventcal.AsEnumerable
           Where MyCalendar.GetWeekOfYear(Row.Field(Of DateTime)("date"),
           CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek,
            DayOfWeek.Sunday) = Currentweek And MyCalendar.GetYear(Row.Field(Of DateTime)("date")) = lastCurrentyear And MyCalendar.GetDayOfWeek(Row.Field(Of DateTime)("date")) = dayname
           Select Row.Field(Of Double)("sales"))
```

Comment: What if we are Feb 1st 2015? There are no equivalent Saturday for last year.

Comment: those kinds of comparisons are usually on a WeekOfYear basis without regard to the month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To whom it may be intrested, here is how you get the equivalent of today's day last year or year before. thanks to tommytwotrain for this solution

```
Private Function Date2Weekday(ByVal d As Date, ByVal y As Integer) As Date
    'determine week
    Dim weekNumber As Integer = Math.Ceiling(d.Day / 7)
    'determine day number
    Dim daynumber1 As Integer = Weekday(d)
    'determine target first day of month
    Dim targetDay1 As Date = New DateTime(y, d.Month, 1)
    Dim targetDay1Number As Integer = Weekday(targetDay1)
    Dim dt As Integer = (weekNumber * 7) + (daynumber1 - targetDay1Number)+1
    If dt > weekNumber * 7 Then dt -= 7
 Date2Weekday = New DateTime(y, d.Month, dt)     
 End Function

Private Function salescalendar(ByVal dtduty As DataTable) As DataTable
   Dim eventcal As New DataTable
    Dim lastyear = MyCalendar.GetYear(Now) - 1
    Dim todays As Date = Now.Date
 Dim dayrecord = (From Row In eventcal.AsEnumerable
                 Where Row.Field(Of DateTime)("date") = Date2Weekday(todays, lastyear)
                Select Row.Field(Of Double)("sales")) 
  end function
```